# Testing Room as JUnit Test Not AndroidTest

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-room

Trying to test room migration using the MigrationTestHelper class and Robolectric. We want it as a JUnit test because our CI environment cannot fire up an emulator.  *(Please no answers with CI fixes for emulators, CI is not in my control)*  Only issue I have is that the test fails because it can't find the schemas.  My build.gradle has this in it already

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        test.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/schemas".toString())
        androidTest.assets.srcDirs += files("$projectDir/schemas".toString())

    test {
        java.srcDirs += "$projectDir/src/sharedTest/java"
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
        unitTests.all {
            systemProperty 'robolectric.enabledSdks', '21'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
   // has all the proper dependencies from mockito adn robolectric to kotlin and junit.
}
```

Here is the test code but again its mostly just the schema can't be found when the database creation is called.  Also the json files are there in the schema directory

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class Migration19To20Test {
    private val migration = MyDatabase.MIGRATION_19_20
    private val fromVersion = 19
    private val toVersion = 20

    @get:Rule
    val helper: MigrationTestHelper = MigrationTestHelper(
            InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(),
            MyDatabase::class.java.canonicalName,
            FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelperFactory())

    private val testDatabaseName = "migration-test"

    @Test
    fun insertsFirmwareVersionFullColumn() {
        givenADatabase()

        val validateDroppedTables = true
        val db = helper.runMigrationsAndValidate(
                testDatabaseName,
                toVersion,
                validateDroppedTables,
                migration)

        db.query("select * from ${DatabaseConstants.Table.People}").use { cursor ->
            cursor.moveToFirst()
            assertTrue("table should contain the ${DatabaseConstants.Column.People.NAME_FULL} column as it should have been added",
                    cursor.columnNames.contains(DatabaseConstants.Column.People.NAME_FULL))
        }
    }

    private fun givenADatabase() {
        // Test fails here
        helper.createDatabase(testDatabaseName, fromVersion)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @JPM Any solution?

Comment: Nope no solution yet, sorry.  I gave up on this for now.

Comment: can you run it as JUnit test? 
I have exception java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException when helper.runMigrationsAndValidate calls

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by copying `MigrationTestHelper` to my test source code and modified loadSchema method to look like this

```
    private SchemaBundle loadSchema(Context context, int version) throws IOException {
//        InputStream input = context.getAssets().open(mAssetsFolder + "/" + version + ".json");
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream("./schemas/" + mAssetsFolder + "/" + version + ".json");
        return SchemaBundle.deserialize(input);
    }
```

The `schemas` directory is configured in build.gradle

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = [
                        "room.schemaLocation"  : "$projectDir/schemas".toString(),
                        "room.incremental"     : "true",
                        "room.expandProjection": "true"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the cause is that this class looks for migration in `assets` directory because Google assumes that you will run those migration on device. In such case you must include them as part of android assets.

With Robolectric it's just reading from a directory and putting that into a stream.

Comment: This does not work for me I get an error saying "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class androidx.room.migration.bundle.FtsEntityBundle declares multiple JSON fields named __robo_data__"

Comment: Are you sure that targeting valid Room JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

My scenario was not exactly the same - I had an instrumented migration test case - but perhaps the cause is the same. If you have something like the rule below, aapt will strip the schema files and it will do so in debug builds as well as release ones.

```
buildTypes {

  debug {...}

  release {
    aaptOptions {
      ignoreAssetsPattern '!*.json'
    }
  }
}
```